# latex sidewaystable not aligned

Tags: tables, rotating

I try to add a table to my document, thus, I used the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable} 
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\label{Label}       
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{2.35cm}|p{3.12cm}|p{3.12cm}|p{3.12cm}|p{3.12cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}& \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX}&  XXXXXX XXXXXXX BXXXXXXX XXXXXX& XXXXXX XXXXXXX  &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX &   XXXXXX XXXXXXX\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX}  &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX  &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX &   XXXXXX XXXXXXX &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{1.5cm}{XXXX}& XXXXXX XXXXXXX & \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} & \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} & \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} & XXXXXX XXXXXXX \\
\cline{2-6}
&XXXXXX XXXXXXX & XXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX & XXXXXX XXXXXXX&  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-}  & XXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXX\\
\cline{2-6}
&XXXXXX XXXXXXX &XXXXXX XXXXXXX &    XXXXXX XXXXXXX &\makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} &\makebox[\linewidth][c]{-}\\
\cline{2-6}
&XXXXXX XXXXXXX  & XXXXXX XXXXXXX & \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} &  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} &\makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} \\
\cline{2-6}
&XXXXXX XXXXXXX & XXXXXX XXXXXXX & XXXXXX XXXXXXX & XXXXXX XXXXXXX &  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX}   & XXXXXX XXXXXXX &    XXXXXX XXXXXXX &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX    & XXXXXX XXXXXXX\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX} &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX &    XXXXXX XXXXXXX &\makebox[\linewidth][c]{-}  & \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX} &   \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} &    \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} &    \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} &    XXXXXX XXXXXXX\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX} &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX &   XXXXXX XXXXXXX &   XXXXXX XXXXXXX& \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

However the table appear like depicted in the attached image
[image]

Comment: That's curious: it's perfectly centered for me.

Comment: Are you using a different document class? Your code works fine here as well, does that exact example produce the misalignment on your system?

Comment: I use a Springer Template thus, my document starts as follow: `\begin{filecontents*}
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{graphicx}`

Comment: You lost me there.  Why don't you just edit your example to demonstrate the actual problem?

Comment: I have the same problem using another template

Comment: Either way, please make sure that the code you post actually reproduce the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is a result of the lines

```
\setlength\@fptop{0\p@}
\setlength\@fpsep{12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\@fpbot{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
```

in `svjour3.cls`.

When you load `rotating` `\rotFPtop` is automatically set to `\@fptop` and `\rotFPbot` to `\@fpbot`. Therefore the rotated table shifts to the right (top).

You can change this if you set `\rotFPtop` explicitly: either to `0pt plus 1fil` or to `\rotFPbot`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%%% the following  5 lines only for simualating the issue
\makeatletter
\setlength\@fptop{0\p@}
\setlength\@fpsep{12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\@fpbot{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\makeatother
%%%

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}% <- add this line after loading rotating
\setlength{\rotFPbot}{0pt plus 1fil}% <- maybe its better to add this line too

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable} 
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\label{Label}       
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{2.35cm}|p{3.12cm}|p{3.12cm}|p{3.12cm}|p{3.12cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}& \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX}&  XXXXXX XXXXXXX BXXXXXXX XXXXXX& XXXXXX XXXXXXX  &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX &   XXXXXX XXXXXXX\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX}  &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX  &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX &   XXXXXX XXXXXXX &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{1.5cm}{XXXX}& XXXXXX XXXXXXX & \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} & \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} & \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} & XXXXXX XXXXXXX \\
\cline{2-6}
&XXXXXX XXXXXXX & XXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX & XXXXXX XXXXXXX&  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-}  & XXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXX\\
\cline{2-6}
&XXXXXX XXXXXXX &XXXXXX XXXXXXX &    XXXXXX XXXXXXX &\makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} &\makebox[\linewidth][c]{-}\\
\cline{2-6}
&XXXXXX XXXXXXX  & XXXXXX XXXXXXX & \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} &  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} &\makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} \\
\cline{2-6}
&XXXXXX XXXXXXX & XXXXXX XXXXXXX & XXXXXX XXXXXXX & XXXXXX XXXXXXX &  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX}   & XXXXXX XXXXXXX &    XXXXXX XXXXXXX &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX    & XXXXXX XXXXXXX\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX} &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX &    XXXXXX XXXXXXX &\makebox[\linewidth][c]{-}  & \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX} &   \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} &    \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} &    \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-} &    XXXXXX XXXXXXX\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX} &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX &   XXXXXX XXXXXXX &   XXXXXX XXXXXXX& \makebox[\linewidth][c]{-}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]