# how to align a sidewaystable in the middle of the page?

Tags: tables, sidewaystable

I have the following table large table which I want to put in the middle of the page.

I have the following two requirements:

1. table should be on a new page
2. table needs to be aligned both vertically AND horizontally.

I tried `centering` which does not work. Any pointers welcome.

**svjour3:**
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-general-template-file-for-the-latex-package-svjour3-for-springer-journals/pbbwqhxxvtbp

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
\documentclass[smallextended,anonymous]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for better formatting columns with decimal numbers
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=1.1]*{12}{S[table-format=2.3]}@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{11}{c}{}   &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{retro}   \\
    \cmidrule{12-13}
{Svieq} & {000436xa} & {000594xa} & {001715xa} & {001932ya}    & {006040ya}  & {006263xa}    & {007162ya} & {007257ya} & {IT0605ya} & {IT0790xa}  & {emiliaeo} &  {emilians} \\   \midrule
0.4 &   2.447   &   2.177   &   2.304   &   4.921   &   4.298   &   2.121   &   3.928   &   3.478   &   3.462   &   1.751   &   0.875   &   0.525   \\    
0.8 &   4.894   &   4.354   &   4.609   &   9.843   &   8.597   &   4.241   &   7.857   &   6.957   &   6.924   &   3.502   &   1.750   &   1.049   \\   
1.2 &   7.341   &   6.530   &   6.913   &   14.764  &   12.895  &   6.362   &   11.785  &   10.435  &   10.386  &   5.252   &   2.625   &   1.574   \\  
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
    \end{sidewaystable}


\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

[image]

Here this table should be in the middle of the page.

Comment: Not a solution, but why don't you just change the columns to rows? It would even be more readable!

Comment: Please always post a complete MWE including `\documentclass` and any packages you are using so that your code is compilable. With packages `siunitx,rotating,booktabs` this compiles fine for me and appears centered in the page.

Comment: @SandyG added full example.

Comment: What is the `\documentclass`?

Comment: updated @SandyG

Comment: This does not compile without `svjour3`, which is not a standard class.

Comment: svjour3: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-general-template-file-for-the-latex-package-svjour3-for-springer-journals/pbbwqhxxvtbp

Answer (score 1):

See [sidewaystable not aligned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/363799/161015)

[image: a]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
\documentclass[smallextended,anonymous]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{rotating}

%% ************ from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/363799/161015
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}% % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\rotFPbot}{0pt plus 1fil}% 
\usepackage{caption}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%% ***********


\usepackage{booktabs}  % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for better formatting columns with decimal numbers
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{sidewaystable}
        \centering
        \scriptsize
        \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=1.1]*{12}{S[table-format=2.3]}@{}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{11}{c}{}   &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{retro}   \\
            \cmidrule{12-13}
            {Svieq} & {000436xa} & {000594xa} & {001715xa} & {001932ya}    & {006040ya}  & {006263xa}    & {007162ya} & {007257ya} & {IT0605ya} & {IT0790xa}  & {emiliaeo} &  {emilians} \\   \midrule
            0.4 &   2.447   &   2.177   &   2.304   &   4.921   &   4.298   &   2.121   &   3.928   &   3.478   &   3.462   &   1.751   &   0.875   &   0.525   \\    
            0.8 &   4.894   &   4.354   &   4.609   &   9.843   &   8.597   &   4.241   &   7.857   &   6.957   &   6.924   &   3.502   &   1.750   &   1.049   \\   
            1.2 &   7.341   &   6.530   &   6.913   &   14.764  &   12.895  &   6.362   &   11.785  &   10.435  &   10.386  &   5.252   &   2.625   &   1.574   \\  
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Caption}
    \end{sidewaystable}     
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Link used in answer is not accessible.